# How can I remove delete button from Dhtmlx Scheduler "onLightbox" event?

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I added the following line in my "onLightbox" event but it doesn't do anything.

```
scheduler.config.buttons_right=[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need to be added before scheduler.init call ( outside of onLightbox event ) as this is a global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think it also could be added inside "onBeforeLightbox" to get more control:

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeLightbox", function (id, mode, event) {
    scheduler.config.buttons_right = [];
}
```